# Cannot figure out how to use "for ... in" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following code expects that all the properties of this.triggeredTests are arrays and calculates their total length:

```
    let savedLen = 0;

    const values = Object.values(this.triggeredTests);

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
      savedLen += values[i].length;
    }
```

if I try to rewrite this code with **for ... in**:

```
    for (const val in values) {
      savedLen += val.length;
    }
```

I got some annoying errors:

```
  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in          The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype
  src\components\entity\Test.vue:171:9
          for (const val in values) {
          ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax  for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array
  src\components\entity\Test.vue:171:9
          for (const val in values) {
          ^


✘ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


Errors:
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in
```

Is it possible to make this **for ... in** work?

I am to sure what compiler I use, but at least I know that I am working in Node.js v8.12.0 environment with NPM.

**EDIT1:**

If I use **for ... of**:

```
    for (const val of values) {
        savedLen += val.length;
    }
```

I am getting another error:

```
    ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations
    src\components\entity\Test.vue:171:9
            for (const val of values) {
            ^
```

**EDIT2:**

This does not produce errors:

```
    const values = Object.values(this.triggeredTests);
    const sumCalculator = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.length;
    const savedLen = values.reduce(sumCalculator, 0);
```

Comment: its not a javascript error, its eslint https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in

Comment: The errors have a link in them explaining the general issue, including ways to solve it. Have you read them?

Comment: Re your edit: the airbnb linter is opinionated about this stuff and doesn't want you to use `for...of`- see [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271).

Comment: It would be `for (const prop in this.triggeredTests) savedLen += this.triggeredTests[prop].length;` if you insisted on `for … in`, but since you are using `Object.values` anyway you don't need any `for … in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't describe the error as *annoying* here - it's trying to protect you from doing something you don't intend. Take the following example code:

```
Array.prototype.someFunc = function () { }

const someObject = { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C' };
const someObjectValues = Object.values(someObject);

for (const v in someObjectValues) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

There are at least two problems here:

1. `v` will be the *index* of the element: instead of `A`, `B` and `C`, you'll get `0`, `1` and `2`.
2. You'll also get `someFunc`, which is clearly not intended.

The simplest solution here is to take note of the linting errors and leave the code as it was.

Comment: what is 'x'? did you mean 'v'?

Comment: Really I am getting '0 1 2 someFunc'. That all is strange... What someFunc does here?

Comment: By adding a function to the prototype like I have in the example, `someFunc` becomes an [enumerable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), which means it will show up in `for...in` loops like it does here. Adding functions to the prototype allows for extending a type in JavaScript. For example, with the code above, you could call `values.someFunc()` and it would be valid (although it does nothing here as it's an empty function).

Comment: Figured this out. With 'for...of' I am getting 'A B C'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing syntax with python, node is enumerating values of iterable objects using for-of

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: "for ... of" produce another annoying error, see EDIT1.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky thats your linter, not interpreter message. You can try Array.prototype.forEach.call(prop). What is the reason for changing the loop? Just curiosity?

Comment: I'll try within 30 minutes. Writing 'for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1)' is also annoying. I'd like it to be shorter.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky speaking about performance, for loop is the fastest. Actually, while( arr.length-- ) { //do stuff } is THE fastest, but its rubbish. 

Id go with forEach anytime I have to iterrate thru Array, you can even cast obj to array, but its also not the best praxis.

Comment: values.reduce() works, see EDIT2

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Drop your linter if it annoys you instead of being useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your error are indeed due to eslint and not for loop in javascript.  You could probably paste what you have into chrome dev tools and it would work just fine without the compilation.

Specifically these lints

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax

Both of these guard against oddness in for loops related to objects in that it will iterate over all the elements.

In this case if that is a basic array, i would recommend using

`values.forEach(iterator)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through an array. The `for...of` loop is what you are looking for.
If you want to use `for...in` then try this

```
 for (const val in values) {
      savedLen += values[val].length;
    }
```

Also have a look here for some good info on both loops https://bitsofco.de/for-in-vs-for-of/

Comment: "for ... of" produce another annoying error, see EDIT1.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)